# Convert array to int php

Tags: php, laravel

Code:

```
public function resolve($root, $args, $context, ResolveInfo $resolveInfo, Closure $getSelectFields)
{

    $valornovo = $args['sacar'];
    $user = User::where('id', $args['id']);
    $fields2 = 'saldo';

    $fields = $getSelectFields();

$valorantigo = (object) $user->with($fields->getRelations())->select($fields2)->first();
$foo = json_decode($valorantigo, true);
$foo2 = array_map('intval', $foo);


return  $foo2;

}
```

It returns the correct value. But I need to convert it to a number (int) to do a subtraction operation.

I converted to array with this:

```
$foo = json_decode($valorantigo, true);
```

Now I need to convert to int. I tried (int) and I couldn't, it returns null.

Edit: what I want is that it returns the value, however it is an integer:

https://prnt.sc/t0ehbd

Vardump:

https://prnt.sc/t0ehhf

I don't know how yet, but he gets exactly the amount I need. But I can't do operations because it is an array

I just want this value, not the whole array https://prnt.sc/t0es0f

Comment: Why not just `return $foo2 * 1` ?

Comment: what do you want exactly? could you provide some clear example? I can't understand what you want.

Comment: I edited the post, forgive the ignorance

Comment: use: return $foo2 *  = https://prnt.sc/t0ej16

Comment: did you try intval($foo['data']['sacar']['saldo']) ? I think this code should work... :)

Comment: you want "saldo" value, right?

Comment: Yes. return = https://prnt.sc/t0em4u

Comment: Yes, "saldo".
But I already have his value, but he doesn't come as an int.

Comment: oh.. my misunderstanding... sorry... let me think again...

Comment: @mateusanjos  you are making GraphQL endpoints. right?

Comment: GraphQL endpoints can't return single value, it should return json value. I think you have already defined output format of that endpoint.

Comment: I think you have to parse the array data at client side to get "saldo" value.

Comment: Original return without converting to array: https://prnt.sc/t0eqn6      

user.php 

 protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'saldo', 'company_id'
    ];


usertype.php:

 'saldo' => [
                'type' => Type::int(),
                'description' => 'The user saldo.',
            ],


Any idea?

Comment: I just want this value, not the whole array https://prnt.sc/t0es0f

Answer (score 0):

json_decode($valorantigo, true) takes a JSON encoded string and returns an associative array.

Based on what I can tell from your data, your associative array contains strings as keys and associative arrays as values as follows:

```
{
  "data": {
    "users": [
      {
        "name": "Rodrigo Cardoso",
        "email": "rodrigo.cardoso@imasters.com.br",
        "saldo": 10,
        "id": 3,
        "company": null
      },
      {
        "name": "Reinaldo Silotto",
        "email": "reinaldo.silotto@imasters.com.br",
        "saldo": 0,
        "id": 2,
        "company": null
      },
      {
        "name": "Alefe Souza",
        "email": "contact@alefesouza.com",
        "saldo": 0,
        "id": 1,
        "company": null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My guess is that you want to return the value of a specific key of a nested array, which you can do like this:

```
array_map(function ($user) {
    return $user['saldo'];
}, $foo['data']['users']);
```

This will return an array with the saldo value for each user.

Comment: I couldn't even test it; -; I was confused. What exactly do I do? I'm not even average in php, just someone really learning.

I tried to replace:

$ foo2 = array_map ('intval', $ foo);

per:

array_map (function ($ foo) {
    return intval ($ foo ['balance']);
}, ['withdraw' => ['balance' => 23]]);

But it didn't even run. The error was: "TypeError: Failed to fetch". I believe I did it wrong.

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify by specifying the exact json encoded string that you are decoding.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/t0f1g5   {
  "data": {
    "users": [
      {
        "name": "Rodrigo Cardoso",
        "email": "rodrigo.cardoso@imasters.com.br",
        "saldo": 10,
        "id": 3,
        "company": null
      },
      {
        "name": "Reinaldo Silotto",
        "email": "reinaldo.silotto@imasters.com.br",
        "saldo": 0,
        "id": 2,
        "company": null
      },
      {
        "name": "Alefe Souza",
        "email": "contact@alefesouza.com",
        "saldo": 0,
        "id": 1,
        "company": null
      }
    ]
  }
}

Comment: I forgot to return var_dump: "int(10)\n{\"data\":{\"sacar\":null}}"

Answer (score 0):

`array_values` — Return all the values of an array :

```
$array = array("id" => 4, "days" => 64);
print_r(array_values($array));
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 64
)
```

Comment: You want like this? If not then please tell me what output you want, I'll try to help